# finding any clicked element using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

I was just wondering if it's possible to find exactly what element was clicked on jsp/html page. I don't want to create any special click function for any particular element. Something like Firebug does.

Comment: ever went through jquery [api](http://api.jquery.com) or [docs](http://docs.jquery.com)??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function(){
    // `this` will refer to the clicked element
})
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `*` selector is unnecessary, since you're deliberately not restricting the elements that should trigger the click.

Comment: The advantage is that `this` receives the targeted element. This way, you're using the same syntax as you would elsewhere. jQuery has various ways of achieving what the OP asked for, but I find a particular point of elegance with the library is that you can often keep syntax very similar to the traditional way — you don't need to invoke the `event` argument or somesuch to achieve the desired ends.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).click(function(event){
  // event.target is the clicked object
});
```

This will work because eventually the click event will bubble up to the document level.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, currently on mobile, but I'd suggest (in plain JavaScript):

```
function wasClicked(evt) {
    var evt = evt || window.event,
          el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
         console.log(el);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) { wasClicked(e); }, false);
```

I believe the syntax for IE's `attachEvent()` method is:

```
document.body.attachEvent('onclick', wasClicked);
```

[JS Fiddle demo (of both)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HEHVQ/).

References:

- [`attachEvent()`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljinxrmt.php).
- [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).